# Jquery não carrega no localhost

Tags: javascript, carregamento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código esta ai, o link para o arquivo do jquery está correto, porem não está carregando o mesmo

Comment: tenta trocar o http por https. E no ultimo inclui ele.

Comment: Inclua sempre o jquery antes, depois plugins etc..

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown tem isso também.

Comment: Pela imagen dá pra ver que o console tá lotado de erros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chama ele usando http ou https assim:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Ou então baixe ele localmente e faça a referência local.

Use estas referências antes das outras referências de javascript.

Fonte: https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Quando você não especifica o protocolo dessa forma: `"//dominio.com/code.js"` o navegador completa com o protocolo da sua página. Se você estiver em `http://localhost/` ele vai pegar o `http`, se estiver `https://localhost` ele vai completar com `https` e isso as vezes causa algum problema.

Outro problema é que a biblioteca principal do jquery sempre deve vir antes de suas derivadas, exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-bxslider.js"></script>
```

Isso porque o código o jQuery precisa ser "definido" para que as outras bibliotecas possam acessá-lo. Se ele for "definido" após as bibliotecas, todas as funções delas que utilizam jQuery vão falhar.